# Search and replace regex in VI, clarification needed

Tags: regex, vi

Given the following, i'd like to comment lines starting with 1 or 2 or 3

```
Some text
1 101 12
1 102 13
2 200 2
// Some comments inside
2 202 4
2 201 7
3 300 0
3 301 7
Some other text
```

The following regex (seems to) look(s) right, and yet it does not work ..

```
%s/^([123])(.+)/#\1\2/g
```

The same regex matches when used by egrep

```
egrep '^([123])(.+)' file_name
```

Please help me understand why this search and replace is failing in VI

Comment: FWIW, `egrep` uses a different regex syntax (the `e` stands for extended). If you'd use `grep` it would not work either.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I saved the link you posted as well. It's a good one http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html#re

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the characters: `()+`.  So you could do `%s/^\([123]\)\(.\+\)/#\1\2/g`, but it seems easier to do: `:g/^[123]/s/^/#`

Note that vi does have various options for changing the meaning of symbols in patterns (`help magic`).  In particular, you could use 'very magic' and do: `:%s/\v^([123].+)/#\1/g` (note that the `g` flag is completely redundant here!)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl,

```
my $t = "Some text
1 101 12
1 102 13
2 200 2
2 202 4
2 201 7
3 300 0
3 301 7
Some other text";

foreach (split /^/, $t) {
  $_ =~ s/^([1-3])/# $1/;
  print $_;
}
```

Result:

```
Some text
# 1 101 12
# 1 102 13
# 2 200 2
# 2 202 4
# 2 201 7
# 3 300 0
# 3 301 7
Some other text
```